# jQuery BlockUI Plugin on MasterPage - IE mouse wait cursor fix

Tags: jquery, master-pages, jquery-blockui

In IE, BlockUI unblockUI doesn't change the wait cursor back to default. The cursor changes back to default the instant it moves a pixel after the unblock though (as if the cursor graphic was changed but the cursor doesn't refresh until it moves a pixel):

I have seen two solutions, both of which are not working for me.  One is adding: 
els[1].style.cursor = 'default'; 
to the remove function which causes a '1.style' is null or not an object JS error.  The other is adding: 
$(o).css('cursor', 'default'); 
to the reset function.  This does not seem to accomplish anything for me.

Maybe my issues are due to the fact that I have the reference to the blockUI on a masterpage.  If anyone could shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I get the same behaviour in Firefox 5.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as to why the cursor remains in wait in IE, but the style of the cursor can be changed in the **onUnblock** event. One would define what to be done on unBlocking. The following works for me. I have checked it in IE-8 and IE-7 (in compatibility mode).

```
        $.blockUI({onUnblock : function(){
                $("body").css({
                    "cursor" : "default"
                })
            }
        });
```

Do let me know if you require further help.

Answer (score 1):

below is the only thing that I have found to work cross browser, including IE's, to get the cursor to refresh both when you want to show the waiting cursor and when you want to take it off. Note that adding and removing a class wont work in IE, it has to be like this.

when you want the cursor to show, do:

```
$("body").css({
    "cursor" : "wait"
})
```

and when you want it to go away

```
$("body").css({
    "cursor" : "default"
})
```